# Is it correct to say that the default constructor for class Point below is constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

B. Stroustrup has the following example on page 265 of his book "TCPL" 4th edition:

```
struct Point{
    int x, y, z;
    constexpr Point up(int d) { return {x, y, z+d}; }
    constexpr Poind move(int dx, int dy) { return {x+dx, y+dy}; }
};
```

Later on page 266 he shows:

```
constexpr Point p1 {10, 20, 30};     // the default constructor is constexpr
```

From §7.1.5/4 in N4140, I find the following pertinent bullet points:

> - (4.4) either its function-body shall be `= default`, or the compound-statement of its function-body shall satisfy the constraints
>     for a function-body of a constexpr function;
> - (4.5) every non-variant non-static data member and base class sub-object shall be initialized (12.6.2);

I have two observations in relation to the bullet points above:

1. Is it correct to say that the compiler generated default constructor for `struct Point` has a function body `= default`?
2. Even if the answer to my question above is `yes`, I'm disputing the fact that the compiler generated default constructor for `struct Point` is `constexpr`, simply because this constructor doesn't initialize the members `x`, `y` and `z`, contradicting bullet point (4.5) above. Am I correct here?

**Edit** I'm introducing a third question that I think summarizes my main difficulty with this issue.

I can't produce an example of a `constexpr` default constructor whose body is equal to `= default`. Suppose this is NOT possible. The obvious question is: what is then the purpose of the bullet point (4.4) in §7.1.5/4?

Comment: `Point p1 {10, 20, 30};` doesn't use default constructor (which, by definition, is a constructor that can be called with no parameters). This is aggregate initialization.

Comment: You're right. The following doesn't compile exactly because of bullet point 4.5: `struct Point{ int x, y, z; }; constexpr Point p2;`. But regarding my first question: can we say that the compiler generated default constructor has a function body `= default`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes. From [class.ctor]:

> If there is no user-declared constructor
>   for class `X`, a non-explicit constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared **as defaulted (8.4)**.

A function implicitly declared as defaulted means it functions as if it were explicitly declared as `= default`.

2. You are correct. The default constructor cannot be used as `constexpr`, further made clear via [dcl.init]:

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type T, T shall be a class type
>   with a **user-provided** default constructor.

So the following is ill-formed, as there is no user-provided default constructor:

```
    constexpr Point p; // error
```

We also see this in [dcl.constexpr]:

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`. Such an object shall have
>   literal type and **shall be initialized**. If it is initialized by a constructor call, that call shall be a constant expression (5.20). Otherwise, or if a `constexpr` specifier is used in a reference declaration, every fullexpression
>   that appears in its initializer shall be a constant expression. *[ Note:* Each implicit conversion
>   used in converting the initializer expressions and each constructor call used for the initialization is part of
>   such a full-expression. *—end note ]*
>   *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> struct pixel {
>     int x, y;
> };
> constexpr pixel ur = { 1294, 1024 };  // OK
> constexpr pixel origin;               // error: initializer missing
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

Since the default constructor doesn't initialize for us (even if it didn't fail the user-provided requirement), we can provide an initializer to do it ourselves:

```
    constexpr Point q{}; // ok, all of q's members are 0
```

---

This is all ultimately irrelevant as this:

```
constexpr Point p1 {10, 20, 30};     // the default constructor is constexpr
```

does not use the default constructor at all and actually performs aggregate initialization, which satisfies the "shall be initialized" clause cited above.

Comment: `A function declared as defaulted means it is declared as = default` Where  did you get this from?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet I think he meant to say the *implicitly-declared* default-constructor is equivalent to a `=default` constructor.

Comment: Though I don't follow with the "The default constructor cannot be used as `constexpr`". [Then why does this work?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cd090851b781b20)

Comment: @0x499602D2 You're value-initializing there

Comment: @François-MarieArouet That's what implicitly declared as defaulted means. It means declared as if it were `= default`.

Comment: `constexpr Point q{};` is also aggregate initialization.

Comment: [What about this example?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4445d48d9735b7ca) `s` is default-constructed then returned.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Hopefully the changed wording is better?

Comment: @0x499602D2 That example relates to issue [253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253) since `S` has no members. Probably both compilers went with the resolution that no members == no initialization possible == no initialization required. If you added `int x;` into it, both compilers would reject it. (ignore my previous comment, now deleted)

Comment: @Barry Could you show me an example of a constexpr default constructor with a function body `= default`? I can't produce one.

Comment: @François-MarieArouet `struct S { constexpr S() = default; };`

Comment: @Barry clang doesn't compile the snippet (gcc does): `struct S { constexpr S() = default; } int main() { constexpr S s; }`. If clang is right, again what is the point of a `constexpr` default constructor with a body `= default`?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet `constexpr S s{};` See [issue 253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253). Also, if you fully define the constructor as `constexpr S() {}`, clang doesn't require the initializer.